# Loop through all buttons in a QButtonGroup

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop

In my project, I have a QButtonGroup with 256 pushbuttons in it. I also gave each button an id like this:

```
void MainWindow::AddBlocksToGroup()
{
    QButtonGroup* blockGroup = new QButtonGroup(this);
    blockGroup->addButton(ui->Oblock_0, 0);
    ...
    blockGroup->addButton(ui->Oblock_255, 255);
}
```

I am trying to loop through all the buttons in the group and change their text but I keep getting errors when my program reaches the part where I loop through the buttons. This is what I currently have to loop through them:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
{
    blockGroup->button(i)->setText("Test"); //Read access violation?
}
```

I always get a read access violation in my loop when my program reaches this point. Why is this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this for the iteration code:

```
foreach(QAbstractButton *button, blockGroup->buttons()) {
    button->setText("Test");
}
```

If this still gives you crashes, then there's something else going on in your program that is invalidating those button pointers.

Comment: Yes I'm still getting errors. Then what else could it be? Did I add the buttons to the group correctly? Also, I added QButtonGroup* blockGroup; to the public class of mainwindow.h

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time, you probably have already solved this. If not, maybe you need to check whether `blockGroup->buttons()` return value is an empty list or not. If it is an empty list, then your program crashes.

Comment: Your answer conceptually is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/18436802/6622587

Comment: Sorry for that I made a mistake. I hadn't used `foreach` before.

Comment: in C++11 forward you can use: `for(QAbstractButton * btn: blockGroup->buttons()){// your logic here}`

Comment: Yeah,that's right. Thanks for this tip. I also heard that using for_each with lamda func will performance well and less time-consuming, if the vector or list has too many elements.

Comment: `foreach` should no longer be used, you must use `for(auto val: container)`

Comment: Will `for_each` cause some problems?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be creating a local variable called `blockGroup` in your `AddBlocksToGroup()` function. Perhaps what you are trying to do is initialize your `MainWindow` member variable that uses the same name?

So instead of: `QButtonGroup* blockGroup = new QButtonGroup(this);`

you should do: `blockGroup = new QButtonGroup(this);`